# Retrieve User Info in OAuth2 Protected Views

Tags: django, oauth

I'm using [django-oauth-toolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit) for my app's OAuth2 implementation. I have the following code:

```
    from oauth2_provider.decorators import protected_resource
    User = get_user_model()

    @protected_resource(scopes=['ifttt'])
    @api_view(['GET'])
    def user_info(request):
        username = request.user.username
        u_id     = request.user.id
        data = {}
        data['name'] = username
        data['id'] = u_id

        rst = {}
        rst['data'] = data
        return Response(rst, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The problem is that the username and ID returned is empty. It seems that the user object cannot be retrieved as if the function is called by an anonymous user, which is not true since OAuth2 requires user authentication.

Maybe it's because it is the client app which the user authorized that is making the call, instead of the user itself? If so, how can I get the user object corresponded to the application? Thanks.

Edit:

I tried to put `request.user` to response but failed, the error is `Anonymous user is not JSON serializable`. So django does think the request is from an anonymous user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the access token in the Header to retrieve the corresponding user. Here the 'Authorization' is like: 'Bearer {token}'.

```
from oauth2_provider.models import AccessToken

def user_info(request):
    app_tk = request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]
    m = re.search('(Bearer)(\s)(.*)', app_tk)
    app_tk = m.group(3)
    acc_tk = AccessToken.objects.get(token=app_tk)
    user = acc_tk.user

    username = user.username
    u_id     = user.id
    # other codes and return
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Not sure why mine doesn't have a **acc_tk.user**. It's just returning a None Type object.

Answer (score 2):

A latecomer here but in case someone comes across this question later, actual answer is about Django configuration.

Follow the instructions on this page: https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_03.html

If you have the right AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS and MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, request.user will be populated after a token based authentication.

Comment: I tried this one and it's just returning me a None type.

Comment: What is your app type? It needs to be authorization_code or implicit. Also make sure you have the right order for your settings. I use the exact same configuration with Oauth2, it works flawlessly.

Comment: Client type: confidential and authorization grant type: client credentials.

Comment: That is the reason why you get a None value, client credentials won't work. There is no association of a user to a token in that model. You can check the database (oauth2_provider_accesstoken) you will see user_id is null. You need to find a model where you can use authorization_code or implicit.

Comment: Ok. I'll look into that. I'm using the oAuth2 as the login process of my users to the 'API'. Now, based from your responses I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: Oauth2 is the right framework for it. Sounds like you need the password model, that should work. Our mobile app does it that way too. Read this short document, sums up oauth2 very well: https://aaronparecki.com/2012/07/29/2/oauth2-simplified

Comment: Password is for resource owner password right? So, are you creating a unique oAuth application per each user?

Comment: Password is for providing  username and password to create a token. You can then use that token to authenticate the user instead of username/password. You will get the user populated in request.user. You do not need a different oauth application for each user. You will have only one application say for your mobile app, multiple users will authenticate by using it.

Comment: Kinda confusing (for me) to implement. I'm about to resort into just use oAuth in implementing other stuff then just use the default Token (if not JWT) Authentication for a logged in user.